# How do I store _m128 SSE register data on an "unsigned char" array?

Tags: c++, stored-procedures, sse

I am new with SSE, so far y have managed to load from the unsigned char arrays but I do not know how to store the result back. Please help me.

```
void calculate_borders_parallel( unsigned char *src, unsigned char *dst, int width, int height )
  {
      // TO DO
      __m128i sourceUp;
      __m128i sourceDown;
      __m128i destiny;

#pragma omp parallel for

     for (int j = 1; j<height; j++)
     {
         for (int i = 0; i<width; i+=4)
         {

             sourceUp = _mm_loadu_si128( (const __m128i*)&src[(j-1)*width+i] );
             sourceDown = _mm_loadu_si128( (const __m128i*)&src[(j+1)*width+i] );
             destiny = _mm_subs_epu8(sourceDown, sourceUp);

             _mm_store_si128( &dst[(j+0)*width+i], destiny );  // <----- ERROR HERE .. cannot convert from __m128i to unsigned char


         }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to do something like:

```
*(__m128i *)&dst[idx]
```

Dereference an address, which was converted to the array of vectors.

Answer (score 1):

You're just missing a cast:

```
         _mm_store_si128( (__m128 *)&dst[(j+0)*width+i], destiny );
```